# Copy object properties maintaining mutability

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, mutable

I need to copy some properties of an object to another object and maintain its mutability.

Here is the source object:

```
var originalObj = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "nestedObj1" : {
    "nestedKey1" : "nestedValue1",
    "nestedKey2" : "nestedValue2"
  },
  "nestedArr1" : [
    {
      "nestedKey3" : "nestedValue3",
      "nestedKey4" : "nestedValue4"
    },
    {
      "nestedKey5" : "nestedValue5",
      "nestedKey6" : "nestedValue6"
    }
  ],
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4"  
}
```

Basically, I only need to copy the keys that are non-objects and non-arrays.
In this example, `key1`, `key2`, `key3` and `key4`

So here is what I did:

```
  var modObject = {}
  Object.keys(originalObj).forEach((child) => {

    // Copy non-objects and non-arrays
    if (typeof originalObj[child] !== 'object' && 
    !Array.isArray(modObject[child])) {
      modObject[child] = originalObj[child]
    }
  })
  
  // Change modObject and expect originalObj is updated to 'value3_modified' as well
  modObject['key3'] = 'value3_modified'
  console.log(originalObj['key3'])  // Outputs 'value3' - Key3 value was not modified
  console.log(modObject['key3'])  // Outputs 'value3_modified'
```

But the problem is, when I update `modObject`, its changes are not propagating to `originalObj`. I know, this is because I am copying it as a value.

So I tried top copy the entire object and just delete the ones that should not be there (arrays and object keys):

```
  // Copy the entire object
  modObject = originalObj

  Object.keys(modObject).forEach((child) => {

    // Delete objects and arrays - these should not be in the new object
    if (typeof modObject[child] === 'object' || 
    Array.isArray(modObject[child])) {
      delete modObject[child]
    }
  })

  // Update modObject and expect originalObj updated to 'value3_modified' as well
  modObject['key3'] = 'value3_modified'
  console.log(modObject)  // Outputs 'value3_modified'
  console.log(originalObj)  // // Outputs 'value3_modified' but object and array keys deleted in originalObj
```

But then, this time, my problem is since it is mutable, the keys that I deleted on the `modObject` also gets deleted in `originalObj`.

How can I achieve what I want:

- Copy non-object and non-array keys from `originalObj` to `modObject` while maintaining its mutability?

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/keechan/hbdj9mcs/11/

Help! Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid this is actually impossible to achieve. At least I can't think of any way how. A variable is a pointer onto an object, not it's properties. So you can't let a variable only point to a subset of properties of an object. What is your actual use-case behind this? Would it be possible to use a function to access the object and then only return those keys you are interested in?

Comment: Primitives are copied, so changing them won't change them in the original object. Only reference types have the behavior that you want.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i don't know what exactly you want, but i assume that you want to cloned original object and want to keep safe original object and modify cloned object.

Check if that works for you.

```
let modObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObj))
```

now do whatever with modObject(cloned) the originalObj dose not affect.

[Stack Overflow: What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)